# Object to deep for desired array, numpy random choice

Tags: python, excel, pandas, numpy, random

This is the code that I've been using to generate a random weighted choice from a baseball game simulator that I've been working on as my first python project.

```
elements = ['1b', '2b', '3b', 'hr', 'bb', 'k', 'out']
        if order_pos_away == 1:
            weights = ab1
        if order_pos_away == 2:
            weights = ab2
        if order_pos_away == 3:
            weights = ab3
        if order_pos_away == 4:
            weights = ab4
        if order_pos_away == 5:
            weights = ab5
        if order_pos_away == 6:
            weights = ab6
        if order_pos_away == 7:
            weights = ab7
        if order_pos_away == 8:
            weights = ab8
        if order_pos_away == 9:
            weights = ab9
        from numpy.random import choice
        c = choice(elements, p=weights)
```

Each time the loop runs through **order_pos_away** is increased by 1 so it will take the next batter's list of probabilities that add up to exactly 1. When the list probabilities are entered manually I have no issues. However, when I try to import them from the excel sheet where they are stored I get the error:

```
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

I've tried multiple ways of getting the excel data into python (read_csv, xlrd, numpy, pandas). Regardless of what I try, I always end up with the same error. I've found no solution for this as much as I've searched and have had difficulty even finding a good explanation of what is happening when I get this error.

Comment: I don't think the code and explaination you provided is enough to help you with the current problem.

Comment: I don't know the meaning of this particular `ValueError`, though I see it comes up occasionally on SO.  But you could help us by showing the stacktrace (e.g. does it occur in the `choice` statement?  And for what `weights`?  If the problem is with loading the weights, we need to have some idea of what the `excel` file is like, and what the various loading methods produce.

Answer (score 3):

Since the problem seems to come up with weights loaded from a file, let's explore how `choice` behaves with so weight arrays:

```
In [227]: elements=['1b', '2b', '3b', 'hr', 'bb', 'k', 'out']
```

default - fine:

```
In [228]: np.random.choice(elements)
Out[228]: 'k'
```

a 1d array that sums to 1 is also fine:

```
In [229]: np.random.choice(elements, p=np.ones(7)/7)
Out[229]: '2b'
```

But a 2d array, even of the right size (columns or rows) produces this error:

```
In [230]: np.random.choice(elements, p=np.ones((1,7))/7)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-230-0be221b99732> in <module>()
----> 1 np.random.choice(elements, p=np.ones((1,7))/7)

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.choice()

ValueError: object too deep for desired array

In [231]: np.random.choice(elements, p=np.ones((7,1))/7)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-231-88812915113a> in <module>()
----> 1 np.random.choice(elements, p=np.ones((7,1))/7)

mtrand.pyx in mtrand.RandomState.choice()

ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Looking up the `ValueError` I saw that it usually came up when using correlation, convolve and and various curve fitting tasks.  That led me to suspect a compiled function - such as `np.choice` - and a dimension issue.  I'm still not quite sure what is the source, but the `.pyx` file in the stacktrace makes me suspect `cython` code.

What you need to do is show us one or more of the problem weights as loaded from the `excel` source.  Focus on `shape` and `dtype`.  It may help to show the sample `csv` file, and one or more to the methods you used to load it.

---

Web search shows this error comes up with `np.convolve` and `np.bincount` as well.  Those too are functions that take 1d arrays as input.